# Why does MySQL ignore the index even on force for this order by?

Tags: mysql, innodb, index, optimization, explain

I run an `EXPLAIN`:

```
mysql> explain select last_name from employees order by last_name;
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+  
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+  
|  1 | SIMPLE      | employees | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 10031 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The indexes in my table:

```
mysql> show index from employees;  
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+  
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name      | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |  
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+  
| employees |          0 | PRIMARY       |            1 | subsidiary_id | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |  
| employees |          0 | PRIMARY       |            2 | employee_id   | A         |       10031 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |  
| employees |          1 | idx_last_name |            1 | last_name     | A         |       10031 |      700 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |  
| employees |          1 | date_of_birth |            1 | date_of_birth | A         |       10031 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |  
| employees |          1 | date_of_birth |            2 | subsidiary_id | A         |       10031 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |  
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+  
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

There is an index on last_name but the optimizer does not use it.
So I do:

```
mysql> explain select last_name from employees force index(idx_last_name) order by last_name;  
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+  
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra          |  
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+  
|  1 | SIMPLE      | employees | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 10031 | Using filesort |  
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------+  
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But **still** the index is **not** used! What am I doing wrong here?
Does it have to do with the fact that the index is `NON_UNIQUE`? 
BTW the last_name is `VARCHAR(1000)`

**Update requested by @RolandoMySQLDBA**

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT last_name) DistinctCount FROM employees;  
+---------------+  
| DistinctCount |  
+---------------+  
|         10000 |  
+---------------+  
1 row in set (0.05 sec)  


mysql> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) Count500,last_name FROM employees GROUP BY last_name HAVING COUNT(1) > 500) A;  
+----------+  
| COUNT(1) |  
+----------+  
|        0 |  
+----------+  
1 row in set (0.15 sec)
```

Comment: Please run these two queries: 1) `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT last_name) DistinctCount FROM employees;` 2) `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) Count500,last_name FROM employees GROUP BY last_name HAVING COUNT(1) > 500) A;`. What is the result of each count ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA:I updated OP with the info you asked for.

Comment: Two more queries, please: 1) `SELECT COUNT(1) FullTableCount FROM employees;` and 2) `SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) Count500,last_name FROM employees GROUP BY last_name HAVING COUNT(1) > 500) A LIMIT 10;`.

Comment: Never mind, I see the explain with what I need.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA:Ok, because I still don't see anything. BTW what was the purpose of the queries?I have no idea what the second query does

Comment: I posted an answer. Just to answer your last question, the last query would show me `last_name` values that make up more than 5% of the table. Due to the cardinality, I realized there are 10000 unique names already. Didn't need it after all.

Comment: @Cratylus you accepted a wrong answer, you should accept the correct [answer of Michael-sqlbot](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48104/2047)

Comment: It is difficult to tell what version of MySQL commenters are using but in version 8, making your index **visible** seems to be important [https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-invisible-indexes/](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-invisible-indexes/). I tried forcing a query to use an index but had no luck until I set the index to be visible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## PROBLEM #1

Look at the query

```
select last_name from employees order by last_name;
```

I don't see a meaningful WHERE clause, and neither does the MySQL Query Optimizer. There is no incentive to use an index.

## PROBLEM #2

Look at the query

```
select last_name from employees force index(idx_last_name) order by last_name;
```

You gave it an index, but the Query Opitmizer took over. I have seen this behavior before ([How do I force a JOIN to use a specific index in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30139/how-do-i-force-a-join-to-use-a-specific-index-in-mysql/30140#30140))

Why should this happen?

Without a `WHERE` clause, Query Optimizer says the following to itself:

- This is an InnoDB Table
- It's an indexed column
- The index has the row_id of the [**gen_clust_index (a.k.a. Clustered Index)**](https://serverfault.com/questions/238845/what-is-gen-clust-index-used-for-in-mysql/239554#239554)
- Why should I look at the index when

  - there is no `WHERE` clause?
  - I would always have to bounce back to the table?
- Since all rows in an InnoDB table reside in the same 16K blocks as the gen_clust_index, I'll do a full table scan instead.

The Query Optimizer chose the path of least resistance.

You are going to be in for a little shock, but here it goes: *Did you know that the Query Optimizer will handle MyISAM quite differently?*

You are probably saying HUH ???? HOW ????

MyISAM stores the data in a `.MYD` file and all indexes in the `.MYI` file.

The same query will produce a different EXPLAIN plan because the index lives in a different file from the data. Why ? Here is why:

- The data needed (`last_name` column) is already ordered in the `.MYI`
- In the worst case, you will have a full index scan
- You will only access the column `last_name` from the index
- You do not need to sift through unwanted
- You will not trigger temp file creation for sorting

How can be so sure of this? I have tested this working theory on how using a different storage will generate a different EXPLAIN plan (sometimes a better one): [Must an index cover all selected columns for it to be used for ORDER BY?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28592/must-an-index-cover-all-selected-columns-for-it-to-be-used-for-order-by/28640#28640)

Comment: -1 @Rolando this answer is not less precise than the correct [answer of Michael-sqlbot](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/48104/2047) but it is wrong, e.g.the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) says:
"MySQL uses indexes for these operations:(...)To sort or group a table if the sorting or grouping is done on a leftmost prefix of a usable index(...)". Also some of the other statements of your post are disputable. I would recommend you delete this answer or to rework it.

Comment: This answer is not correct. An index may still be used even if there is no WHERE clause if it avoids sorting.

Comment: Mysql still uses an index for the ordering of the rows, even if there is no WHERE clause mentioned.

Answer (score 20):

Actually, the problem here is that this looks like a prefix index. I don't see the table definition in the question, but `sub_part` = 700?  You haven't indexed the whole column, so the index can't be used for sorting and is not useful as a covering index, either.  It could only be used to find the rows that "might" match a `WHERE` and the server layer (above the storage engine) would have to further filter the rows matched.  Do you really need 1000 characters for a last name?

---

**update** to illustrate:  I have a table test table with a litle over 500 rows in it, each with the domain name of a web site in a column `domain_name VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL` and no indexes.

```
mysql> alter table keydemo add key(domain_name);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

With the full column indexed, the query uses the index:

```
mysql> explain select domain_name from keydemo order by domain_name;
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | keydemo | index | NULL          | domain_name | 764     | NULL |  541 | Using index |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

So, now, I'll drop that index, and just index the first 200 characters of domain_name.

```
mysql> alter table keydemo drop key domain_name;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table keydemo add key(domain_name(200));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> explain select domain_name from keydemo order by domain_name;
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | keydemo | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  541 | Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Voila.

Note also, that the index, at 200 characters, is longer than the longest value in the column...

```
mysql> select max(length(domain_name)) from keydemo;
+--------------------------+
| max(length(domain_name)) |
+--------------------------+
|                       43 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

...but that doesn't make any difference.  An index declared with a prefix length can only be used for lookups, not for sorting, and not as a covering index, since it doesn't contain the full column value, by definition.

Also, the above queries were run on an InnoDB table, but running them on a MyISAM table yields virtually identical results.  The *only* difference in this case is that the InnoDB count for `rows` is slightly off (541) while MyISAM shows the exact number of rows (563) which is normal behavior since the two storage engines handle index dives very differently.

I would still assert that the last_name column is likely larger than needed, but it still is *possible* to index the entire column, if you are using InnoDB and running MySQL 5.5 or 5.6:

> By default, an index key for a single-column index can be up to 767 bytes. The same length limit applies to any index key prefix. See Section 13.1.13, “`CREATE INDEX` Syntax”. For example, you might hit this limit with a column prefix index of more than 255 characters on a `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` column, assuming a `UTF-8` character set and the maximum of 3 bytes for each character. When the [`innodb_large_prefix`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix) configuration option is enabled, this length limit is raised to 3072 bytes, for `InnoDB` tables that use the `DYNAMIC` and `COMPRESSED` row formats.
>
> <sup>— http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-restrictions.html</sup>

Comment: Interesting point of view. The column is `varchar(1000)` but this is beyond the max allowed for index which is ~750

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated the answer to illustrate that it's not just theoretical.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: @ypercube This answer is more precise than mine. +1 for your comment and +1 for this answer. May this should be accepted instead on mine.

Comment: Question: Can a prefix index be used for NULL range queries? Index: `some_char(1), some_datetime`. Query: `SELECT ... WHERE some_char IS NULL AND some_datetime < '2016-01-01'`. The index seems *perfect* for this query. Is it? `EXPLAIN` says it uses the index, but also says `Using index condition; Using where`.

Comment: @Timo, that's an interesting question... which I would suggest posting as a new question, here, perhaps with a link to this answer, for context.  Post the complete output from `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, as well as `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` and `SELECT @@VERSION;` since changes to the optimizer across versions may be relevant.

Comment: @Timo - Prefix indexes are almost never useful.  This Q&A is yet another example of that statement.

Comment: Update:  The manual quote refers to 5.5.  5.7 defaults to large_prefix and 3072, so most 767 issues are eliminated.

Comment: By now I can report that (at least for 5.7) a prefix index **does not help** with indexing null, as I asked for in my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

I made a answer about because a comment will not support formating and RolandoMySQL DBA talked about  gen_clust_index and innodb.
And this is very important on a innodb based table.
This goes further than normal DBA knowledge because you need to be able to analyse C code..

You should ALWAYS ALWAYS make a PRIMARY KEY or an UNIQUE KEY if you are using Innodb.
If you don't innodb will use it's own generated ROW_ID which could do you more harm than good.

I will try explaining it easy because the proof is based on C code.

```
/**********************************************************************//**
Returns a new row id.
@return the new id */
UNIV_INLINE
row_id_t
dict_sys_get_new_row_id(void)
/*=========================*/
{
    row_id_t    id;

    mutex_enter(&(dict_sys->mutex));

    id = dict_sys->row_id;

    if (0 == (id % DICT_HDR_ROW_ID_WRITE_MARGIN)) {
          dict_hdr_flush_row_id();
    }

    dict_sys->row_id++;
    mutex_exit(&(dict_sys->mutex));
    return(id);
}
```

**First problem**

mutex_enter(&(dict_sys->mutex));

This line makes sure only one thread can access dict_sys->mutex at the same time. 
What if already the value was mutexed... yes a thread has to wait so you get something like a nice random feature like **thread locking** or if you have more tables without your own PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE KEY then you would have an nice feature with innodb '**table locking** ' isn't this not the reason why MyISAM was replaced by InnoDB because off the nice feature thats called record/row based locking..

**Second problem**

(0 == (id % DICT_HDR_ROW_ID_WRITE_MARGIN))

modulo (%) calculations are slow not good if you are batch inserting because it needs to be recalculated every time..., and because DICT_HDR_ROW_ID_WRITE_MARGIN (value 256) is a power of two this could be made much faster..

(0 == (id & (DICT_HDR_ROW_ID_WRITE_MARGIN - 1)))

**Side note if the C compiler was configured to optimize and it is an good optimizer, the C optimizer will fix the "heavy" code to the lighter version**

**motto of the story always create your own PRIMARY KEY or make sure you have a UNIQUE index when you create a table from the start**

Comment: Add row-based replication and the fact that row ID's are not consistent across servers, and Raymond's point about always creating a primary key is even more important.

Comment: Please don't suggest that `UNIQUE` is sufficient -- it also needs to include only non-NULL columns for the unique index to be promoted to PK.

Comment: "modulo (%) calculations are slow" -- More important is what percent of the time of an `INSERT` is spent in this function.  I suspect is insignificant.  Contrast the effort to shovel columns around, do BTree operations, including an occasional block-split, various mutexes on the buffer_pool, change-buffer stuff, etc.

Comment: True @RickJames the overhead might be very small number but many small numbers also add up (would still be a micro optimisation).. Besides the the first problem is the most trouble some