# why is this query taking so long?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

```
+----+-------------+-----------+----------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Id | User        | Host      | db       | Command | Time | State    | Info                                                   |
+----+-------------+-----------+----------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 39 | tigase_user | localhost | tigasedb | Query   | 5406 | updating | delete from tig_pairs where uid >= 2 and uid <= 700000 |
| 40 | tigase_user | localhost | tigasedb | Query   |    0 | NULL     | show processlist                                       |
+----+-------------+-----------+----------+---------+------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

It just stays in the 'updating' state for most of the 5406 seconds. Mysql version Server version: 5.1.69-0ubuntu0.11.10.1-log (Ubuntu)

thanks

```
 mysql> select count(*) from tig_pairs;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  6275968 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.84 sec)

mysql> show create table tig_pairs;
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table     | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| tig_pairs | CREATE TABLE `tig_pairs` (
  `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pkey` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `pval` mediumtext,
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `pkey` (`pkey`),
  KEY `nid_pkey` (`nid`,`pkey`),
  CONSTRAINT `tig_pairs_constr_1` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `tig_users` (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC |
+-----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please add the table definition (output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tig_pairs;`) so we know  engine used and indexes. And how big is the table, how many rows?

Comment: Thank you for adding the info. I suspect the text column and that the query deletes a large part of the table play a role in the huge delay but it may be something else. One and a half hour for a delete, even if it is deleting 7M rows sounds too long.

Comment: Have you tried to time the operation when deleting in chunks (of say, 700 statements with 1000 different `uid` each) instead of one big `DELETE`?

Comment: Check your /tmp/ dir if there is an MYD / MYI file there then your query is running as an disk based table what is very slow. if not delete an smaller range. This could also be an reason (article that i wrote here) http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48072/why-does-mysql-ignore-the-index-even-on-force-for-this-order-by/48184#48184

Comment: If you delete way more than half of the data it could be ore efficient to copy data you want to keep to a new table and then `TRUNCATE` the table. TRUNCATE simply drops everything, DELETE goes row by row, while keeping MVCC guarantees